# React Native: Finish current screen (component) after on press

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I have a React Native app Android-based and I'm navigating from a Screen A to Screen B.

Screen B is a component that has a Text Input and uses an update button to save the new value.

---

[image: Screen B]

### **Screen B**

What I'm looking is to dismiss/finish Screen B after the button is pressed, and having a flow that looks like this:

Screen A -> Screen B (Finish screen and come back to) -> Screen A

Nonetheless, when I press the Back Arrow button in the Android device after I come back to Screen A the app still comes back to Screen B :(

The render method in **Screen A**

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View styleName="horizontal" style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.captionDarkGray}>
            {this.props.user.name}
          </Text>
          <View style={styles.alignHorizontalRight}>
            <Text
              style={styles.editButton}
              onPress={() =>
                this.props.navigation.navigate("ScreenB", {
                  fieldName: "Name",
                  fieldValue: this.props.user.name
                })
              }
            >
              Edit
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

The **Screen B** code is:

```
export class ScreenB extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  dimissScreen() {
    // Finish this Component
  }
  render() {
    const fieldName = this.props.navigation.getParam("fieldName", "NO-ID");
    const fieldValue = this.props.navigation.getParam("fieldValue", "NO-ID");

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBarBackground />
        <View style={styles.globalBar}>
          <Text style={(styles.h3, { marginLeft: 10 })}>
            Update {fieldName}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={localStyles.content}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder={fieldValue}
            defaultValue={fieldValue}
            style={(styles.formFieldEditText, localStyles.editText)}
            onSubmitEditing={() => this.phoneNumberInput.focus()}
            keyboardType="default"
            autoCapitalize="words"
            autoCorrect={true}
            placeholderTextColor={Colors.grayDark}
            maxLength={30}
          />

          <ButtonMm onPress={() => this.dimissScreen()}>Update</ButtonMm>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And the **Stack Navigator** of the Router looks like this:

```
export const RootAppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ScreenA: {
      screen: ScreenA,
      navigationOptions: { header: null }
    },
    ScreenB: {
      screen: ScreenB,
      navigationOptions: { header: null }
    },
    OtherScreen: {
      screen:...
```

Is there any way to sort of call **finish()** for Screen B (Like when we finish an  **Android Activity** ) once the update button was pressed?
I think in this way, on back pressed the Screen A will not come back to Screen B.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post what you have written to finish B ?

    dimissScreen() {
    // Finish this Component
    }

Comment: The navigation is an array of view, you can remove view at index and it's work.

Comment: @TheHound.developer actually that is my question, what to write there? Lol

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use this in order to go back if you can not in the same stack

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack(null)}
```

you can also use pop if you are in the same stack and want to go back to the previous screen

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.pop()}
```

if you want to go two screens back try this

```
this.props.navigation.pop(2)
```

Comment: Actually your answer of onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack(null)} worked!
Feel free to update it in order to mark it as the right one, thanks!

Comment: @MuhammadShaheem what should I do if I want to go two screens back by finishing them?

Comment: @S.M.Asif please check ans i just updated it check if things workout for u.

Answer (score 4):

This worked fine for me

```
 this.props.navigation.replace('YourPageRoot');
```

Answer (score 1):

please try the below code

```
  <Button
      onPress={() => goBack()}
      title="Update"
    />
```

Comment: first part of this answer should be a comment

Comment: onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack(null)}